# ValueError: time data '2021-11-11 05:01:12.11111' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p'

Tags: python, datetime, utc, strptime

Just made a similar post, but thought I should give another example of an issue that is relatively the same. I enter in my code

```
utc = dt.strptime(timeEntry.get(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p")
```

and get

```
ValueError: time data '2021-11-11 05:01:12.11' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p'
```

Anything would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: The `.11` refers to the millisecond component, so try this format - `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan You're a lifesaver!! No clue how that blew over my head. Thank you so much.

Comment: I voted to close this as not reproducible/caused by typo. Please have a look at the docs, section [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) - parsing directives have to match the input, they don't do magic.

Comment: I'm new to the community, and you are correct. Is there any way for me to close this myself? @MrFuppes

Comment: I think you can vote on your own question to close it.

Comment: @MrFuppes Unfortunately, it seems as if I'm a little too new to the community, and can't even vote yet! Hopefully others will see this and vote to close, if anything I'll just come back to it once I've asked/answered a few more questions. Again, thanks for all the help!